# Avfundation Video Array swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, avcomposition

Good afternoon I have a question about a function I'm doing in swift 3.

I'm making an app that uses the camera and records video but the bed will record continuously and at the time you press a button it will be saved the last minute it was recorded and will continue recording if you want to save another minute.

I already managed to record 60 videos of 1 sec but they are recorded as an mp4 file on the phone, but now I need to put them together to form a 1 min file, but in order to do this I need to create an array of the videos before they are saved, so that they can be put together before That are saved and only have a file of 1 min instead of 60 of 1sec.

Example: I have this on my phone when I record.

```
 0Video.mp4
 1Video.mp4
 2Video.mp4
```

These are already stored on the phone but I need instead to keep them in memory as an array.

```
`Var array [type] = {oVideo, 1Video, 2Video}`
```

But I do not know what kind of array it is or how to put them together before it is saved, Thanks

Comment: This question is a little confusing.  Can you post code that shows how you are creating those videos?  Why are they only 1 second each?  It sounds like you ultimately want to have them be 60 seconds in length.